# How can Hazelcast client be notified of an another added or removed client

Tags: hazelcast

There's an application stack containing of

- 2 embedded hazelcast apps; (app A)
- 2 apps using hazelcast clients. (app B)

**App B** needs to coordinate task execution among the nodes, so only one node executes a particular task.

With **app A** it's rather easy to implement by creating a gatekeeper as a library, which needs to be queried for a task execution permit. The gatekeeper would keep track of hazelcast members in the cluster, and assign permit to only a single node. It would register a `MembershipListener` in order to track changes in the cluster.

However, **app B**, being a Hazelcast client, can't make use of such gatekeeper, as clients can't access `ClientService` (via hazelcastInstance.getClientService()), thus it's unable to register a `ClientListener` (similar to MembershipListener, but for client nodes) to be notified of added or removed clients.

How could such coordination gatekeeper be implemented for applications that join the cluster as `HazelcastClient`s?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to use a listener on a member (take the oldest member in the cluster and update the listener when the "master" changes) and use an ITopic to inform other clients.

Can't think of another way right now.

Comment: So members (ie not clients) would be implementing the gatekeeper and keeping track of the clients, and update individual client nodes about the change via an `ITopic`?

Might just work, but this would introduce race condition in my case, as the (client-facing) gatekeeper's permit-assigning method would be locally cached.
Now clients would need to flush the cache once notified, so new master could be decided (or told also via the ITopic) and stored in an IMap.

Btw, what exactly do you mean by "take the oldest member in the cluster"?

Comment: Oldest member in the cluster is a little bit "equalerer" than other members ;) Oldest member is `HazelcastInstance::getCluster::getMembers` and take the first element in the returned set. This is always the member with special "master alike" privileges, as stated in the javadoc: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Cluster.html#getMembers--